# Beginning with SQL - dummies guide

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, macos

This is going to be the most simple question, but I'm new to this and can't figure out what to do. I am trying to learn Microsoft SQL for work, I have bought a course and started the modules. The problem is I cannot practice because I don't have SQL or any sort of database installed on my computer. And I have a mac! How can I practice - is there a database and version of sql that I can download on my mac, or is there some other way I can practice on my mac.
Apologies for the simple question, I'm fine with learning new languages, it's just the system requirements I don't get!

Comment: Questions looking for tools are generally off-topic on Stack Overflow, and your question will likely be closed and removed, but one option to get you started with the basics is [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) that can run MS SQL queries online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in the same situation I have a mac and I needed to learn SQL for work so i Used this site : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp 
Its not a class but you can use its test database that is all online and through the browser. 
Hope this helps. If not put windows OS on your mac using bootcamp and install the programs on the windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

There is mac sql client can find on:

http://www.macsqlclient.com/

But there is no version of sql server available for MAC till date.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question again, but what does a sql client do...don't you need a remote SQL Database to connect to, which I don't have